# Mixed content error nginx+docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-container

I have an EC2 with Nginx setup & there are a few containers running inside. There's a Node JS gateway which is serving some of the requests in a webpage hosting in this Nginx server. Nginx is not a container - FYI. While we are able to load the website using https://domainname.com, while doing a refresh, we see some errors in the developer console for some of the elements within the page. The error is as shown in the screenshot attached. I have put redirection in the Nginx so that any http requests are redirected to https, but these 4 or 5 components are not working. I am not sure what is the issue here, and how to resolve. However, I am confident someone might have faced the same issue.

Requesting immediate support here.

[image]